# Transforming c# console app to c# windows form app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, input, console

i have a simple number guessing console app that i want to take it and transfer it to a Windows form app . I changed the output of to a windows form an i know how to change the look of the window (color , height , width , etc) but i'm not sure on how to receive input from user's. Any guidance would be helpful. I'm sort of a newbie so excuse me for my ignorance . Below is the console scrip code

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

         ;

            string appName = "Number Guesser";
            string appVersion = "1.0.0";
            string developer = "Jeffrey 'Jay-Dot' Pernia ";

            //change the color of the words //

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;


            Console.WriteLine("{0}: version {1} by {2}", appName, appVersion, developer);


            //change color back to normal //

            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

            Console.WriteLine("What is your name ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello {0} lets play a game.... ", input);
            while (true)
            {
                Random random = new Random();

                int actualNumber = random.Next(1, 11);
                int guess = 0;

                Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 - 10 ....bet you cant get it right!!");

                Console.ResetColor();
                while (actualNumber != guess)
                {
                    string userGuess = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (!int.TryParse(userGuess, out guess))
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("Put an actual number -_- ");

                        Console.ResetColor();

                        continue;
                    }

                    guess = Int32.Parse(userGuess);

                    if (guess != actualNumber)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("Told you ...loser ! ");

                        Console.ResetColor();

                    }



                }
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("Wow you're good !");
                Console.ResetColor();

                Console.WriteLine("Play again [Y or N]");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

                if (answer == "Y")
                    continue;
                else if (answer == "N")
                    return;
                else
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
```

[Snipper of Window form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U54WP.png)
**EDIT**   i know how to create a window but basically i want to be able to take the user input and have them press enter or return and keep going with my program in the same window w/o having to use a new one

Comment: As an option you can have a `TextBox` on form and let them to enter number in the `TextBox` and press a `Button` to confirm the entered number.

Comment: You may want to do a search on form “events” as a console is not event driven. The console has only one input… the keyboard. A form with buttons, grids and text boxes has many inputs and they are usually handled with “events”. There are events for buttons, textboxes etc…

Comment: Sorry i should had clarified i do have a winform file open and have these 3 lines in my main    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());                    ........................................the issues is i want everything to happen sequentially how it would happen in a console ....i don't want a new window popping up for every event ............thanks for the feed back though !

Comment: Who said a window would pop up for every event?

Comment: i edited my original post to ...i hope is a little more clear on what i'm trying to accomplish

Comment: What do you want to happen after the user types something into the text box and then presses the “enter” key?

Comment: Well a new line saying...Hello {0} lets play a game.... followe by the statement "guess a number from1 -10 " and if shes right then a message telling the user appear and a message otherwise

Comment: From the picture, There is already one ‘Label` and a `TextBox` for the name. Drop another label and another text box for the user to enter a number into for their guess. Then maybe add a button for the user to “click” to “check” if the guess is right. You could add another `Label` to display the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you will do is create `winfows form app`

File > New > Project > Windows Forms Application

Main form designer window will open and on the left side you will have `Toolbox`

From Toolbox drag and drop `TextBox` to the window you just created and position it.

After doing that, press that TextBox and on the right you will see property window.

Inside property windows you will have 5 icons on top of it (Categorized, Alphabetic, Properties, Events, Property Page). Press Events and it will bring list of all events for selected element.

Find `KeyDown` event and double click on field next to it. It will automatically create event in your code like this:

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Inside event put check `If user pressed enter` and inside it you put your logic from console application:

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        //Insert your logic here
        MessageBox.Show("Your result is: " + result.ToString());
    }
}
```

And that is it.

If you want to communicate with user, you could drag/drop `label` from `Toolbox` and communicate via it with `label.Text = "Hello user"`

Comment: THANK YOU ! this is helpful

Comment: If you need anything else feel free to ask. Also if it was helpful, please up vote answer or if it solves your problem tag it as good answer (under downvote button)

Comment: Thanks will do....i up voted it but since i'm knew to stack overflow it says it will have to wait for my reputation points to get to 15 lol

Comment: Then just check it

Comment: oh okay lol...this website has so many features ! ..just did it